# Is it possible to initialize array to capacity without initializing internal objects?

Tags: c#, arrays

Consider I know the length and type of the array I need, I can do as such:

```
KnownType arrayName = new KnownType[knownSize];
```

But this code will also initialize the internal objects, consider a circumstance where I am simply copying from another array into this new array. I would not need to initialize these internal objects. I would simply need the empty space where said objects could be stored.

Is there a way to create an array of a specific capacity without initializing the internal objects?

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: What makes you say that 'this code will also initialize internal objects'? Are you talking about an array of structs or classes?

Comment: If I where to do 'int arrName = new int[5]' I could access the elements and they would be their default value of 0.

Comment: I think we need to have a talk about reference and value types

Comment: Only value types are initialized with their default value

Comment: Arrays are always initialised with zero values (which is `null` for reference types) when they are created, so it is not possible to avoid this. However, it is an extremely fast operation because behind the scenes it will be accomplished using something like a call to [`SecureZeroMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you, that is rather confusing, since value types are still objects. That basically answers my question.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: how fast depends on the types though, i could imagine a struct which contains several other structs and a lot of fields.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It doesn't matter what the type is - no constructors are ever called. It can always be accomplished with a call to something equivalent to `ZeroMemory()`. If you write some timing code, you'll see that it only varies with the size of the array in bytes; it doesn't vary by element type.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: i don't know `ZeroMemory` but there surely is a difference(in CPU and memory) between initializing an `int[] array = new int[100000]` and a `HeavyStruct[] array = new HeavyStruct[100000]` which contains many fields that are also structs.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm saying that the time depends on the size of the array in bytes, which of course will be bigger for bigger element types. But it is still extremely fast since it can use a call to something equivalent to `ZeroMemory()`. My point is that the only thing that matters is the final size of the array in bytes (and it is just as fast when initialising an array with 1,000,000 elements of size 100 or 100,000,000 elements of size 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an array of a specific capacity without initializing the internal objects?

In short: NO. You are always stuck at least with the default value.

As far as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays) tell us when creating a `new` array:

> The new operator is used to create the array and initialize the array elements to their **default values**.

In this case reference types will get `null`

It sounds reasonable to initialize the default values, since the memory is already allocated and cannot be used for anything else. So why not initialize already the values.

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

> This array contains the elements from array[0] to array[4]. [...] In this example, all the array elements are initialized to zero.

**EDIT: Distinction Reference Value Types**

> Consider the following array declaration:

```
SomeType[] array4 = new SomeType[10];
```

> The result of this statement depends on whether SomeType is a value type or a reference type. If it is a value type, the statement creates an array of 10 elements, each of which has the type SomeType. If SomeType is a reference type, the statement creates an array of 10 elements, each of which is initialized to a null reference.

Comment: This is why I suggest `List<T>(Int32)`. I know it's not an array but it is a container.

Comment: @tymtam I know, but I guess the question was: "Is there a way to create an **array**"

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
var myArray = new KnownType[10];
```

This will create space for 10 items, but the items will not be created.  Then you can do:

```
myArray[0] = new KnownType();
```

And THIS will initialise the object.

Comment: The items technically *are* created, but they are created with default values: Null for reference types, zero values for value types. But this is accomplished with the equivalent of `ZeroMemory()` rather than by calling a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

@Mong Zhu's answer goes to the root of the question, but I think it's worth pointing out that some others containers, for example `List<T>`, have  constructors that take in capacity and allow pre allocation and in a case of a reference type, e.g. a class, the objects will not be initialized - the container will only allocate the space and fill it with nulls.

List's [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) that take in capacity:

> `List<T>(Int32)`  Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has the specified initial capacity.

Comment: It might be me, but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question

Comment: @TheGeneral It is not only you ;)